# How do i remove an event from the code without manually deleting it?

Tags: c#, winforms

Sometimes when you accidently double click on events it generates the events event method and add and event handler in the `InitializeComponent()` of the form.

So when I want to delete the event, I have to delete code in two places, the event method it self and the event handler in to `InitializeComponent()`. But is there away to do this without deleting code manually?

Comment: just delete event from the cs file then goto form designer and make any changes and save it again the handler will be deleted automatically from the designer.cs otherwise i think it is not possible using any other way.

Comment: some times when there are 10 - 15 events to be deleted manual deletion is some what hectic, in situations like when I have go through some one else's code and there are about 10-15 unused events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have have not edited the event handler body, you can simple remove the event using VS Designer. For this select Events in Properties window and remove the handler that you don't need.

However, if you have edited the event handler (i.e. the body contains some code or comments). You can still remove the event using above step. But from the cs file you have to manually delete the method. This helps to refrain from designer generated code (and possibility of messing it up).